# Python , variable store in memory

Tags: python

```
a=[1234,1234] #list

a      
[1234, 1234] 

id(a[0])      
38032480

id(a[1])      
38032480

b=1234 #b is a variable of integer type

id(b)      
38032384
```

Why id(b) is not same as id(a[0]) and id(a[1]) in python ?

Comment: In python,value 1234 have to get only one memory location .why id(b) show different memory location.answer the question plzz.

Comment: not really an answer but some insight on interning (for strings): http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/ . it seems like the list constructor does some interning by default.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I think it's the `int` constructor doing the interning, not `list`.

Comment: but in Python , if I write a=1 ; b=1; both id(a) ==id(b) but now it gives different output.

Comment: @aman-tyagi: interning of integers is not guaranteed! if i remember correctly, integers from -5 to 255 are interned (have the same id) in the standard CPython interpreter; the rest may or may not be interned. and this is an implementation detail and should never be relied upon. always compare integers with `==` and never with `is` to get reliable results.

Comment: @hiro protagonist: so do you agree,  that value 1234 is store in one memory location and a[0] ,  b and a[1]  refers to a same memory location.

Comment: @aman-tyagi: yes, if the `id`s are the same, your variables point to the same 'memory location', if the `id`s differ then not.

Comment: @ hiro protagonist: In that case a[0] , a[1] refers to (38032480) memory location that have 1234 value and 'b' refers to (38032384)  memory location that have 1234 value .means , it is possible that same value have store in different memory location .

Comment: @ hiro protagonist: I think python behavior is different if the integer size is small and large.

Comment: @Aman Tyagi : Assume that Python optimizes memory by reusing location of constants in memory and that is not so smart to catch all possible moments. That's enough for a beginner and continue learning. If your code ever depends on this optimization, it is bad bad code because Python didn't promise you anything in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

When the CPython REPL executes a line, it will:

1. parse, and compile it to a code object of bytecode, and then
2. execute the bytecode.

The compilation result can be checked through the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```
>>> dis.dis('a = [1234, 1234, 5678, 90123, 5678, 4321]')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1234)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1234)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (5678)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (90123)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (5678)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 (4321)
             12 BUILD_LIST               6
             14 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             16 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that all 1234s are loaded with "`LOAD_CONST 0`", and all 5678s are are loaded with "`LOAD_CONST 1`". These refer to the constant table associated with the code object. Here, the table is `(1234, 5678, 90123, 4321, None)`.

**The compiler knows that all the copies of 1234 in the code object are the same**, so will only allocate one object to all of them.

Therefore, as OP observed, `a[0]` and `a[1]` do indeed refer to the same object: the same constant from the constant table of the code object of that line of code.

When you execute `b = 1234`, this will again be compiled and executed, **independent of the previous line, so a different object will be allocated.**

(You may read http://akaptur.com/blog/categories/python-internals/ for a brief introduction for how code objects are interpreted)

---

Outside of the REPL, when you execute a `*.py` file, each function is compiled into separate code objects, so when we run:

```
a = [1234, 1234]
b = 1234
print(id(a[0]), id(a[1]))
print(id(b))

a = (lambda: [1234, 1234])()
b = (lambda: 1234)()
print(id(a[0]), id(a[1]))
print(id(b))
```

We may see something like:

```
4415536880 4415536880
4415536880
4415536912 4415536912
4415537104
```

- The first three numbers share the same address 4415536880, and they belong to the constants of the "__main__" code object
- Then `a[0]` and `a[1]` have addresses 4415536912 of the first lambda.
- The `b` has address 4415537104 of the second lambda.

---

Also note that this result is valid for CPython only. Other implementations have different strategies on allocating constants. For instance, running the above code in PyPy gives:

```
19745 19745
19745
19745 19745
19745
```

Comment: so you agree that this has to do with the `list` constructor and not the `int` constructor? (don't want to be smart about it; just curious) +1 anyway! thanks for the answer.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Actually neither, it has to do with the compiler. By the time the list constructor is called, it is already seeing two identical objects.

Comment: oh, ok! sorry, that should have been obvious from the disassembled code... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule or guarantee stating that the id(a[0]) should be equal to the id(a[1]), so the question itself is moot. The question you should be asking is why `id(a[0])` and `id(a[1])` are in fact the same.
If you do `a.append(1234)` followed by `id(a[2])` you may or may not get the same id. As `@hiro protagonist` has pointed out, these are just internal optimizations that you shouldn't depend upon.

Answer (score 1):

A Python list is very much unlike a C array.

A C array is just a block of contiguous memory, so the address of its first (0-th) element is the address of the array itself, by definition. Array access in C is just pointer arithmetic, and the `[]` notation is just a thin crust of syntactic sugar over that pointer arithmetic. An expression `int x[]` is just another form of `int * x`.

For the sake of the example, let's assume that in in Python, `id(x)` is a "memory address of X", as `*x` would be in C. (This is not true for all Python implementations, and not even guaranteed in CPython. It's just an unique number.)

In C, an `int` is just an architecture-dependent number of bytes, so for `int x = 1` the expression `*x` points to these bytes. 
Everything in Python is an object, *including numbers*. This is why `id(1)` refers to an object of type `int` describing number `1`. You can call its methods: `(1).__str__()` will return a string `'1'`.

So, when you have `x = [1, 2, 3]`, `id(x)` is a "pointer" to a `list` object with three elements. The `list` object itself is pretty complex. But `x[0]` is not the bytes that comprise the integer value 1; it's internally a *reference* to an `int` object for number 1. Thus `id(x[0])` is a "pointer" to that object.

In C terms, the elements of the array could be seen as pointers to the objects stored in it, not the objects themselves.

Since there's no point to have two objects representing the same number 1, `id(1)` is always the same during a Python interpreter run. An illustration:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 100, 1000]

assert id(x) != id(y)  # obviously
assert id(x[0]) == id(y[0]) == id(1) # yes, the same int object
```

CPython actually preallocates objects for a few most-used small numbers ([see comments here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_FromLong)). For larger numbers, it's not so, which [can lead to two 'copies' of a larger number having different `id()` values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/223424).

Answer (score 1):

You must note that: id() actually gives id of the value of variables or literals. For every literal/value that is used in your program (even when within the id() itself), id() returns (attempts to return) an unique identifier for the literal/variable within the program life-cycle. This can be used by:

- User: to check if two objects/variables are the same as in: a is b
- Python: to optimise memory i.e. avoid unwanted duplications of same stuff in memory

As for your case, it isn't even guaranteed that a[0] and a[1] will give the same id though the value of both can be the same. It depends on the order/chronology of creation of literals/variables in the python program lifecycle and internally handled by python.

Case 1:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=[1234,1234] 
>>> id(a[0])
52687424
>>> id(a[1])
52687424
```

Case 2 (Note that at the end of case , a[0] and a[1] have same value but different ids):

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=[1,1234]
>>> id(1)
1776174736
>>> id(1234)
14611088
>>> id(a[0])
1776174736
>>> id(a[1])
14611008
>>> a[0]=1234
>>> id(1234)
14611104
>>> id(a[0])
14611152
>>> id(a[1])
14611008
>>>
```